# Trouble with returning the correct data with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on  figuring out why a seemingly correct mysql query is not returning the correct results. I've been given a couple of files to look at, and I believe this (code below) is where the culprit lies. Unfortunately, I don't have all of the files in my possession (working on this for a friend) so it's difficult for me to do any var_dumps or testing. Instead I created my own mock search script which returns the correct result--though the queries are the same.

original:

```
function build_generic_where_clause ($the_query_string) {
    $where_clauses = Array();
    $the_query_string = $this->db->quote($the_query_string);
    array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.name like '%$the_query_string%'");
    if (is_numeric($the_query_string)) {
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_alternate like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_fax like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_office like '%$the_query_string%'");
    }

    $the_where = "";
    foreach($where_clauses as $clause)
    {
        if(!empty($the_where)) $the_where .= " or ";
        $the_where .= $clause;
    }

    return $the_where;
}
```

But this one fails because I'll have say two items such as:

```
Newstate Inc.
Welders of New York
```

and the query above only returns Newstate. However, if I type %new into the search box, both items are returned. I need to get it where just typing in 'new' will return both of them.

My mock query for testing:

```
public static function getAccount($the_query_string){
    $con = drake::connectDB();

    $query = "select * from accounts where name like '%$the_query_string%'";

    $result = $con->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo($row['name']).'<br />';    
    }
}
```

And that one returns both items successfully when searching for 'new'. My best guess would be the $this->db->quote($the_query_string); is adding something to the search string that's somehow altering it so it doesn't return exactly what the query is made to be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Run the query formed in your phpmyadmin from $query

Comment: Yep, running it in phpmyadmin also returns both items successfully.

Comment: what is in the_query_string ??

Comment: best Way to echo  `Query String` with WHERE clause so you can see it output the expected query

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use

```
$the_query_string = mysql_real_escape_string($the_query_string)
```

to eleminate any unexpected or special charater to be escaped.Hope this will help you.
Please let me knowthe status in comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have him give it a shot. Might be a bit of a delay but I'll be sure to mark your answer correct if it works out.